# Regular Expressions with Hyphens seem broken when using Boundaries?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Am I being dense, or do boundaries seem to break the matching of hyphens in JavaScript regular expressions?

```
var string1 = "example words";

/\bexample\b/.test(string1); // true (all good)

var string2 = "-example -words";

/\b-example\b/.test(string2); // false (confusion)
```

Maybe I've misinterpreted the boundary behaviour?

Escaping the hyphen doesn't seem to help either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because `\b` is word boundary and `-` or hyphen is already considered a non word character. You can use this regex insstead:

```
/-example\b/.test('-example -words');
true
```

Comment: There's no use for `\b` in `-\be` anymore, you can remove it

Comment: Of course. So the answer was: yes, I am being dense. Apologies. Is there a better special character for matching words seperated by **space characters** OR **end/beginning of line characters**? I'm essentially wanting a primitive element.className regex. Matching the `-example` in a className that could be `-example`, `-example -some-other`, `-even -more -examples -to -be -had`...

Comment: @shennan: For matching `space characters OR end/beginning of line characters` you can use `(?:^|\s|$)`

Comment: Roger that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `-` is not a "word character".  `\b` matches the boundary between a word character and a non-word character.  The space before the `-` does not match this definition.